# Kinetic.js custom hit region using arc

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm working on KinaticJS(Latest version) since three months.

I face issue to customize hit region with arc() function.I want hit region exactly as shown in an image below.

[image]

I am using following code but it takes whole minor arc as it's hit region.I only need dark(Black) part shown in image as a hit region.

```
drawHitFunc: function(context) {          
    context.beginPath();
    var x = 90;
    var y = 100;
    var radius = 67;
    var startAngle = 1 * Math.PI;
    var endAngle = 2.0 * Math.PI;
    var counterClockwise = false;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
    context.closePath();
    context.fillStrokeShape(this);
},
```

Can anybody advice on this.

Thanks for your time and consideration in advance.
-Naitik

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi lavrton,Thanks for helping me again.I did it in some manner but i think it's not proper way of coding(Something missing) need to fine tune this. http://jsfiddle.net/ewebkraft/zPLkn/ .Please advise if something more beautiful available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use `cache` and `drawHitFromCache`: http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/zPLkn/1/

```
circularText23.cache({
    x : -67 - 5,
    y : - 67 + -5,
    width : 132 + 15,
    height : 132 + 10
});
circularText23.drawHitFromCache();
```

Comment: Thanks for your timely response buddy.

Comment: Hello,sceneFunc seems not calling when apply click event on it.http://jsfiddle.net/zPLkn/2/ please advise.

Comment: Because shape is cached. Use `shape.clearCache();` before changing scene function.